# Bake and export texture

Tags: texturing, export, workflow

After i textured my object in node editor(using image textures-PBR-Diffuse,Nromal and Roughness) how can i export those textures to use them Unity/Unreal to texture the model ?(I know that this involoves a long workflow and if is too hard to explain you can reccomend me some tutorials )